# Get Maven's module classpath at runtime

Tags: java, maven, runtime, classpath, processbuilder

I wan to run java app in different process, and use classpath of another maven module. How can I do that? I try that stuff:

```
String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
            String path = System.getProperty("java.home") + separator + "bin" + separator + "java";             

ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(
              path,
              "-cp",
              //System.getProperty("java.class.path"),
              ".." + separator + nodeProperties.getClasspath(),
              nodeProperties.getMainClass());
            processBuilder.directory(new File(".." + separator + nodeProperties.getWorkingDir()));
            Map<String, String> env = processBuilder.environment();
            env.put("jmx-port", "8000");
            env.put("mode", "SUPER_PEER");
            processBuilder.inheritIO();
            try {
                Process process = processBuilder.start();
                process.waitFor();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("SuperPeer stopped");
```